# Looking to get specific value from list inside of a dict

Tags: python

I have a list of data below. I am trying to pull "bid_price" from the data.

```
current = requests.get("https://www.deribit.com/api/v2/public/get_book_summary_by_instrument?instrument_name=BTC-PERPETUAL").json()
```

Using print(current), I receive this data

```
{  
   'jsonrpc':'2.0',
   'result':[  
      {  
     'volume_usd':566908519.99,
     'volume':79073.94,
     'quote_currency':'USD',
     'open_interest':48034981,
     'mid_price':7059.63,
     'mark_price':7060.06,
     'low':6686.25,
     'last':7057.75,
     'instrument_name':'BTC-PERPETUAL',
     'high':7581.75,
     'funding_8h':1.576e-05,
     'estimated_delivery_price':7057.61,
     'current_funding':0.0,
     'creation_timestamp':1557711700003,
     'bid_price':7059.5,
     'base_currency':'BTC',
     'ask_price':7059.75
      }
   ],
   'usIn':1557711700003222,
   'usOut':1557711700003412,
   'usDiff':190,
   'testnet':False
}
```

I have tried to use "xbt_bid_price = current['result']['bid_price']" - which throws a "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I am unsure how to gain access to the "bid_price" value specifically. It seems like this should be easy to do, but for some reason I cannot seem to figure this one out.

FWIW, I have also tried "xbt_bid_price = (current.get[0]0)" -- which failed as well.

**EDIT:**
Question has been solved, all answers provided worked - thanks! Command needed was: xbt_bid_price = current['result'][0]['bid_price']

Comment: `current['result'][0]['bid_price']`?

Comment: BTW the update you made in the question works only if you have one element in your list, if you have more than one you want to iterate over the list @MargeJohns . Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

When you do `current['result']['bid_price']`, you provide the index `bid_price` to the list `current[result]` which results in an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".`

So you need to use list indexes in order to fetch your data, by iterating over the list.

```
current = {
   'jsonrpc':'2.0',
   'result':[
      {
     'volume_usd':566908519.99,
     'volume':79073.94,
     'quote_currency':'USD',
     'open_interest':48034981,
     'mid_price':7059.63,
     'mark_price':7060.06,
     'low':6686.25,
     'last':7057.75,
     'instrument_name':'BTC-PERPETUAL',
     'high':7581.75,
     'funding_8h':1.576e-05,
     'estimated_delivery_price':7057.61,
     'current_funding':0.0,
     'creation_timestamp':1557711700003,
     'bid_price':7059.5,
     'base_currency':'BTC',
     'ask_price':7059.75
      }
   ],
   'usIn':1557711700003222,
   'usOut':1557711700003412,
   'usDiff':190,
   'testnet':False
}

#Iterate over the list result
for li in current['result']:
    #Get the bid price
    print(li.get('bid_price'))
```

The output will be

```
7059.5
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

your data:

```
current = {  
   'jsonrpc':'2.0',
   'result':[  
      {  
     'volume_usd':566908519.99,
     'volume':79073.94,
     'quote_currency':'USD',
     'open_interest':48034981,
     'mid_price':7059.63,
     'mark_price':7060.06,
     'low':6686.25,
     'last':7057.75,
     'instrument_name':'BTC-PERPETUAL',
     'high':7581.75,
     'funding_8h':1.576e-05,
     'estimated_delivery_price':7057.61,
     'current_funding':0.0,
     'creation_timestamp':1557711700003,
     'bid_price':7059.5,
     'base_currency':'BTC',
     'ask_price':7059.75
      }
   ],
   'usIn':1557711700003222,
   'usOut':1557711700003412,
   'usDiff':190,
   'testnet':False
}
```

here you can get bid price

```
v = current['result'][0]['bid_price']
print(v)
```

output

```
7059.5
```

Answer (score 0):

current["result"] gives a list with one item (the dictionary) as there are square brackets before the braces.

Try the following to get the bid price.
    xbt_bid_price = current["result"][0]["bid_price"]